# Is there anyway I can attach an Excel file to my HTML or Javascript, to be used as a database?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I want to auto-populate a person data on my website, and I need it to get data from an Excel file. So that, the data on my website will automatically change if its updated on Excel. Sadly I need to do this using only vanilla Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot* use vanilla JavaScript to pull data from an Excel file located on your server. However, if you want to populate data on your page from a markup file and use something like [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) or [XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp), that is much more doable and I think answers your use case. Here's a simple example:

`data.js`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open('GET', 'data.json');

xhr.onload = function() {
  build_table(xhr.response);
}

function build_table(data) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    result += build_row(data[i]);
  }
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML += result;
}

function build_row(data) {
  var result = '<tr>';
  result += '<td>' + data.firstname + '</td>';
  result += '<td>' + data.lastname + '</td>';
  result += '<td>' + data.country + '</td>';
  result += '</tr>';
  return result;
}
```

`index.html`:

```
<head>
  <title>AJAX Example</title>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="data">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

`data.json`:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "country": "United States"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Alice",
        "lastname": "Lastname",
        "country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Bob",
        "lastname": "Bobson",
        "country": "United States"
    }
]
```

If you must work with Excel data, I would use the Python `openpyxl` and `json` libraries to read and write your data to this markup file, respectively, though I'm sure similar libraries exist for the language of your choice.

I don't think the following applies, but just for the sake of completeness: if it's an option for you, you could have your webserver build this HTML before it's served, using one of a number of options for your data access layer (`openpyxl` being one of them).

* It is, literally speaking, possible to access an `.xlsx` file via AJAX, unzip it using `zip.js` or similar, and process its XML contents. I do not think you want to do this.